# NHibernate version property is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, concurrency, fluent-nhibernate

Using Sharp Architecture / Fluent NHibernate, I set-up a `Version` property (with an `int`) for my class, however, even though updating its objects correctly updates the Version number, no error is thrown and the versions are basically merged instead of throwing an exception.

```
public class MyClassMap : IAutoMappingOverride<MyClass>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<MyClass> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Version(x => x.Version);
        mapping.OptimisticLock.Version();
    }
}
```

Notice the version is different between two concurrent commits, yet nothing happens.

What gives?

**Edit:** Here's the code:

```
    public ActionConfirmation SaveOrUpdate(IncidenciaDetalleModel model)
    {
        Incidencia incidencia = model.Codigo == null
                                    ? new Incidencia(Convert.ToInt32(model.Solicitante.Id))
                                    : Load(model.Guid);

        TransferFormValuesTo(incidencia, model);

        // Invoke Sharp NHibernate's SaveOrUpdate()
        Incidencia saved = base.SaveOrUpdate(incidencia);

        return ActionConfirmation.CreateSuccessConfirmation(saved);
    }



    private void TransferFormValuesTo(Incidencia incidencia, IncidenciaDetalleModel model)
    {
        incidencia.Resumen = model.Resumen.Trim();
        incidencia.Descripcion = model.Descripcion.Trim();
        incidencia.Solicitante = model.Solicitante.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        incidencia.Regional = regionalTask.Load(model.Regional.GetRegionalId());
    }
```

Comment: show the code which updates. do you use `session.Merge()`?

Comment: No, I use the regular session.SaveOrUpdate(). I'll show code in about an hour when I get to work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please show the code which saves the changes to the database.

Comment: @DanielSchilling Here you go (code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you said the Version updates fine so not applying Conventions fall out.

i guess there is no real concurrent update. you use `Load(model.Guid)` which doesnt load the object from database but creates a proxy for it. it is loaded in `TransferFormValuesTo` updated and immediatly saved. Only between `TransferFormValuesTo` and `SaveOrUpdate()` there can be a race condition leading to stale objects.

you could enable logging for "NHibernate.SQL" to see if the Update of client 1 really is after the the SELECT of client 2